# Parameters - Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: vb.net, excel, parameters, oledb

I'm new to `vb.net` and stackoverflow. I'm currently in a little project where the application will take an excel file and upload it to an access database backend.

At the moment I have managed to import the excel file as I want into a datatable (`dt`) but am having problems then updating the backend access database.

I imagine my problem is with the parameters that are being passed - I Keep getting '**Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors**' and have tried setting datatypes. Any help would be appreciated

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(Connect)
        Dim Update As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update Queries SET SubjStatus=@P1, Status=@P2, Age=@P3, ClosedDate=@P4, ClosedTime=@P5, ClosedBy=@P6, ClosedByRole=@P7 " & _
                                             "WHERE Study=@P8 AND RVLID=@P9 AND VisitName=@P10 AND FormName=@P11 AND PageNo=@P12 AND FieldName=@P13 AND Description=@P14" & _
                                             " AND CreateDate=@P15 AND CreateTime=@P16 AND CreatedBy=@P17", con)

        'Get values from excel - datatable 
        With Update.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@P1", dt.Columns("Subject Status"))
            .AddWithValue("@P2", dt.Columns("Query Status"))
            .AddWithValue("@P3", dt.Columns("Query Age (days)"))
            .AddWithValue("@P4", dt.Columns("Query Closed Date"))
            .AddWithValue("@P5", dt.Columns("Query Closed Time"))
            .AddWithValue("@P6", dt.Columns("Query Closed By"))
            .AddWithValue("@P7", dt.Columns("Query Closed By Role"))
            .AddWithValue("@P8", dt.Columns("Protocol Number"))
            .AddWithValue("@P9", dt.Columns("Screening Number"))
            .AddWithValue("@P10", dt.Columns("Visit Name"))
            .AddWithValue("@P11", dt.Columns("Form Name"))
            .AddWithValue("@P12", dt.Columns("Page Number"))
            .AddWithValue("@P13", dt.Columns("Field Name"))
            .AddWithValue("@P14", dt.Columns("Query Text"))
            .AddWithValue("@P15", dt.Columns("Query Creation Date (UTC)"))
            .AddWithValue("@P16", dt.Columns("Query Creation Time (UTC)"))
            .AddWithValue("@P17", dt.Columns("Query Created By"))
        End With

        'Execute SQL Command
        con.Open()
        Update.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Do you have any primary key defined in your database table?

Comment: I do, I have a compound key

Comment: I would check one by one that parameters. And avoid at all cost AddWithValue. The more precise Add(name, type).Value = xxxx is preferable to AddWithValue that decides by itself the parameter type

Comment: Thanks for the advice Steve, I've switched them over. I am having success with looping through the rows
`.Parameters("@P18").Value = row("Query Closed By Role"`   etc... Seems like a slow method to update though. There must be better

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a decent solution using a combination of these two links

1. [Update DataAdapter1](http://.Add(%22@P18%22,%20OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar,%20255,%20%22Query%20Closed%20By%20Role%22))
2. [Update DataAdapter2](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/423833/datatable-to-access-database-table)

I defined my parameters as follows

```
.Add("@P6", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar, 255, "Page Number")
.Add("@P7", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar, 255, "Field Name")
```

I needed to make sure the rows in datatable (dt) were set for it to think changes has happened.

`For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
If row.RowState = DataRowState.Added Or DataRowState.Unchanged Then 
row.SetAdded() 
End If 
Next`

Then I could update using data adapter (After defining update, insert commands)

`da.update(dt)`

Please someone let me know if there is a better method.